# Which information contains apk sign key (android app)?

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore, apktool

Does it contain some information about system where apk was signed? Some OS info or something like this? I heard someone say it contains mac address of the device where apk was signed. Is it true? What kind of information Google can get from signed apk?

Answer (score 5):

> Someone says it contains mac adress of the device where apk was signed. Is it true?

No it is not

> What kind of information Google can get from signed apk?

Anything you put into the keystore: meaning name(if inputted), company(if inputted), address(if inputted).

Basically: Google gets nothing else than what you insert into the keystore. They don't get your address unless you write it in there. They don't get your name unless you add it. The mac or IP address is not in there.